# Rewrite just part of url

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've got this type of urls on my site (as you can see dashes usage is quite random):

```
http://www.example.com/my_sub_directory/this--is--the-page-title---excellent-title
http://www.example.com/my_sub_directory/this-is--the--page-title--excellent-title
http://www.example.com/my_sub_directory/this-is-the-page----title---excellent---title
```

And I would like to rewrite them in the following format

```
http://www.example.com/my-sub-directory/this-is-the-page-title-excellent-title
```

As you can see the numbers of dashes in the original url is variable. Is this possible? Can I do it for all urls or can I just do it globally?

Can you please also provide a simple example on how to rewrite this

```
http://www.example.com/my_sub_directory/
```

into this

```
http://www.example.com/my-sub-directory/
```

Many thanks

Comment: Is the triple hyphen before "excellent-title" a requirement?  How do you know that isn't part of the "this-is-the-page-title" ?

Comment: It's just an example of random use of dashes in the url, I'll update the question to provide more examples

Comment: I can't see a difference between the last two URLs

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible? Can I do it for all urls or can I just do it globally?

Yes, but not with an `.htaccess` rule.  You could use a `RewriteMap prg:`  *if* you have root access to the system or vhost config.  However what you can do is some think like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /

RewriteRule ^(.*?--.*)$        remapper.php?url=$1  [L]
```

Then use the remapper script to munge the url parameter and issue a `header("Location: ...")` to do a 302 redirect to the "normalised" URI.

Re: the `my_sub_directory/` rewrite, this is trivial for a fixed directory string, but the general case would need to be handled as above:

```
RewriteRule my_sub_directory/  my-sub-directory/    [L]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is there any way of doing this like a normal rewrite without doing a 302 temporary redirect?

Comment: Only if you have root access to the system or vhost Apache config -- then you could use a rewrite map. Otherwise -- no. The 302 redirect is a permanent one, so the client browser will cache this and you'll only do it once per client.

Comment: OK. The only thing here is that I don't want to lose all my page indexed by google. The old site is using the old urls, and the new site is using the new ones. So the only thing I really care about is that google will still be able to find the old urls.

Comment: That's a different issue add [canonical links](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) to your old urls.  Google will track and resolve old to new.  Ditto Bing, Yahoo and the other major engines.  If you don't want to redirect then buy yourself a VPS and you can use RewriteMaps :-)